# Should a woman wear a gartel?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla, women, clothing

My understanding of the halachic need for a [gartel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/172/wearing-a-gartel) is very limited; is there any reason a woman should or should not wear one during prayer?

Comment: לא תלבש may be involved

Comment: That a woman should not wear a man's garment may, indeed, be involved (or not), but that would still have to account for there being a difference between men and women that would over-ride the reason why men wear a gartel in the first place. I thought wearing a gartel had something to do with making a seperation between one's heart, which should be turned towards the sacred, and one's base instincts, as represented by male organs of reproduction. Why would a woman be different, if that is, in fact, the reason for wearing a gartel? (Big 'if' there.)

Comment: @ba So wear a pink gartel. I know of no men who wear those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the reason for wearing a gartel is to prevent even accidentally one's heart from seeing one's private parts (which anyway must be covered to pray) as outlined in [Alex's answer to the linked question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/189/759), then it would seem there is no need for a woman to wear a gartel, as the Shulchan Aruch rules in OC 74:4 that due to their anatomical layout, women can never have the issue of her heart seeing her private parts. This ruling actually has a very practical outcome for many Ashkenazi women who recite a bracha on the mikva when standing naked in the water (cf. Shulchan Aruch YD 200 with Shach and Taz).

Comment: i'm not sure i understand how wearing a belt prevents your heart from seeing your ervah. furthermore it would seem that the halacha is based on amos 4:12 which is pretty generic, so it would seem to me that your answer is they have no obligation to wear one; however i would assume that the mishnah berura's dictate of a measure of piousness would apply to a woman who wore one for prayer.

Comment: @vram As mentioned in Alex's answer, the advantage of a belt is it helps keep your pants up, hence my language of "even accidental". I think the point of Hikon is to do things as prep that are relevant to davening not just random. As little a purpose as it serves for men, at least a belt serves _a_ purpose. If all you care about is Hikon, then a women should do something at least partly relevant, such as wash her face, brush her teeth, fix her makeup or whatever.

Comment: Many of those wearing a gartel also wear suspenders , but no belt. Maybe the clothes could "take off" from the skin revealing the privates to the heart, though the whole body remains covered as seen from the outside. A gartel on top of the clothes would prevent that. As Double AA says, this issue does not exist for women; they only need to be covered outwards.

Comment: +1 The shulchan aruch you bring says that this is true when they are sitting, but are not the woman in the mikva standing?

Answer (score 1):

there is no need for women to wear a gartel. the reason for wearing a gartel has to do with the heart no seeing ones ervah but this is not an issue for women as they may say a brechah when in the not clothed in the mikvah. in addition there could be issues of beged isha if using what is commonly refereed to as a gartel

Comment: What does this answer add?

Comment: +1 why can the woman say the brocho naked?