# Is wearing unisex clothes considered beged ishah?

Tags: clothing, lo-yilbash

There are many examples of cases where t-shirts or hats are given out to a group of people consisting of men and women. Since they are worn by women, are these, and any other unisex clothes like this, considered beged ishah?

Comment: or since they are worn by men why not ask if they could be begged ish?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/32113/759

Comment: Rav Yehuda and his wife shared a unisex cloak. Nedarim 49b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

The Shulchan Aruch ([YD 182:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&st=&pgnum=252)) lists examples of things that constitute beged isha and then qualifies "in a place where where no one wears such clothing and adorns with such adornments except women."

That is, a beged is only beged isha if it is exclusively so. Therefore, by definition, unisex clothing is not beged isha.