# Question about the Tallit

Tags: tallit-gadol

I am not Jewish but I would like to know what the significance is with the different number of stripes on the different tallit. I am compelled to buy one but want to purchase the right thing. I would like to know all I can about the Tallit, so as not to break any cultural or law that God has given.

Comment: Thanks for your question. This seems to be a duplicate of the question linked to above unless you mean specifically that you're asking about the **number** of stripes and not the stripes themselves. Are you?

Comment: What compels you to buy one please?

Comment: Please see [this discussion] of optional observances for non-Jews, and the particular focus on the restriction against performing this Mitzvah.

Comment: @SethJ For some reason, your link to a discussion is broken.

Comment: Assuming from your name Janice that you are a woman, there is a strong cultural taboo against women wearing men's clothing, based on [Deuteronomy 22:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0522.htm#5). This is not necessarily forbidden in the case of tallit, but it is a factor.  See [this link](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31460/3483) for an extensive summary.  The question of a gentile performing a mitzvah is a separate issue, but if a gentile is not bound by Jewish law, and they are not bothering any Jews with their practice then . . .

Comment: http://www.wikinoah.org/index.php?title=Optional_observances_for_non-Jews

Comment: @SethJ Thanks for fixing the link.  I like how it lists opinions both permitting and forbidding tallisim for gentiles.