# Wearing a gartel and a belt?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, clothing

For those who hold by wearing a gartel for davening (for separating the upper and lower body), is it necessary when already wearing a belt?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/172/wearing-a-gartel

Comment: It seems that the gartel acquires a form of "holiness" as it is designated specifically for prayer, whereas a belt is worn for holding up your pants, or for personal adornment. I'm surmising that the belt and gartel serve two separate purposes.

Comment: http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/197385-%D7%92%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9C

Comment: @GershonGold Perhaps consider expanding that into an answer?

Comment: @Scimonster: I do not know who the Rabbi is and he does not give any sources, therefore the comment.

Comment: See Aruch Hashulchan 91:4

Answer (score 1):

Halachically there is a requirement to have a separation so that one's lower half is separate from their heart. This is taken care of by wearing pants, even without a belt, as the pants form a clear distinction. Another reason to wear a gartel is to prepare oneself for prayer. The Kohanim used to wear a gartel as part of their avoida, and today prayer is called avoida shel lev, and so in that sense many have a minhag to use the gartel to help change one's mindset when approaching davening.

Comment: Kohanim would also wear turbans and not wear shoes.

Comment: interesting point and today we wear yarmulkes and some wear hats as well. in reference to not wearing shoes outside of service in the beis hamikdash (may we once again be able to) there is an accepted practice that only mourners go barefoot during tefila

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. Are you saying yes or no?

Comment: yes or no to what?

Comment: @Dude to wearing a gartel with a belt (or even without).

Comment: depends on how you view wearing a gartel. if you are doing so just for the sake of separating one's heart from your nakedness then anything the causes a separation would be sufficient including a belt. however, the other reason one wears a gartel is based on the posuk "Prepare to meet Hashem" (Amos 4:12) and so puting on a gartel is part of getting in the mindset of being ready to pray.