# (Tefach) Wide Gartel

Tags: minhag, tefilla, clothing, shiurim-measurements

Some use a very wide [gartel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/172/3073). A friend of mine mentioned an *inyan* (Judaism-sourced idea) that the gartel should be wider than one *tefach*. Can someone source this *inyan* that the gartel should be (more than a *tefach*) wide — or the lack thereof?

Interestingly, [the priestly gartel](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1008233/jewish/Kli-Hamikdash-Chapter-8.htm#footnoteRef44a1008233) was slightly less than a *tefach*.

[image: Wide gartelach]

Comment: Is that the boy who finished shas

Comment: any boy in bnei brak, nothing special :)

Comment: @sam, yes, that is. The man to the left is the Toldos Aharon Rebbe and the one on the right is the bachur's father.

Comment: it doesn't need to be. there are many who wear a gartel which is as wide as a shoelace. how wide and even how long or other dimensions are purely personal preference.

Comment: @Dude Not purely. Some groups have a well-established custom to wear very wide gartel, and the kohanim MUST wear a wide gartel.

Answer (score 1):

After a further clarification question, I have understood from R' Berel Bixenspanner (Montreal, QC) that there is indeed no reason for a *tefach* wide *gartel*, only one wider than three *etzba'os* (fingerbreadths). The priestly garment would thus satisfy this. (Note that according to some opinions, a *tefach* is in fact only four *etzba'os*, and not usually held five.)

The reason is avoiding *lavud b'gufo shel adam al pi kabbalah*: Just as two surfaces that are separated by a gap of less than three *tefachim* are considered connected in regular Jewish law, so too are two areas of the human body considered connected when separated by less than three *etzba'os* – according to Jewish mysticism. Therefore, a narrower *gartel* may not properly divide the body halves.

Comment: What would the priestly garment satisfy?

Comment: Do you mean this? "Interestingly, the priestly gartel was slightly less than a tefach."