# What is the difference between an avnet and an aizur

Tags: tefilla, words, clothing

I have seen the question on Mi Yodeya titled [Wearing a gartel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/172/wearing-a-gartel)

The [Shulchan Aruch 91:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.91.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes even though you are wearing an *'avnet'* you should still wear an *'aizur'* to daven.

One wonders, **what is the difference between them?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111935/discussion-on-question-by-interested-chasidim-wear-a-gartel-which-i-think-is-wro).

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered in chat but will do so again here. The mishne berura oz v'hodor mevuar brings from kaf hachaim that the avnet was under the garment and aizor on top. The kohanim certainly didnt have it under, and I think that is not the only difference. The avnet was like a piece of string whereas the aizor more like a belt.
He brings from a sefer shevet hakhozi (someone younger than me) that a gartel doesnt have to be tight. I dont agree with the whole concept of a gartel today.
The idea of an aizur is to be 'mezuraz' like a soldier wears a belt to be ready for action. In the olden times people wore like the kohanim a 'ksones' a loose fitting, dress like garment which needed an avnet (gartel) to become mezuraz. This was normal like a lady today wears a belt on a loose dress. Today when people wear tight fitting buttoned jackets a gartel has no place. No one wears a belt on top of that and looks ridiculous. The idea of preparing for davenning is not just to wear anything even if it looks ridiculous. Perhaps if you wear a kaftan or bekisha, they do come usually with a belt but not a normal jacket or coat today. If a belt is not tight it isnt a belt, and has no purpose so I dont agree with the previous sefer.

Comment: @dov what do you think of this